# Docusign checkbox is in the wrong location

Tags: docusignapi

I am using embeded signing and I have noticed that the checkbox's are in different locations at different stages.

I can either make it look correct while doing embeded signing... the check mark is centered in the box, or I can make it so that the check marks (X's) are properly centered in the summary pdf.

However I do not know how to consistently get the check marks to align in both the embeded interface, or the pdf summary...

anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you're hoping for but -- unfortunately, there are not separate settings to specify the location of a form field during signing versus on the completed document (PDF). You only get one opportunity to specify a field's location (during the Create Envelope process), and DocuSign then automatically determines location of the field in the completed document (PDF) -- presumably using the same coordinates that you specified during the "Create Envelope" process, although not always exact (as you've discovered with the checkbox element).

So, the best advice I can offer is to always verify placement of fields BOTH in the signing view AND in the completed view -- and then use trial and error to specify field location in a way that produces best overall results across both views.